# Django || SyncDb || Create nvarchar fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, nvarchar

I'm just starting with Django and am trying to create a db table with nvarchar fields as opposed to varchar.

I'm using MySQL and creating objects of type models.CharField() within my classes.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Patrick

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, MySQL's equivalent to an `NVARCHAR` is a `VARCHAR` with a utf8 character set. Here's the [MySQL reference page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-national.html) for the subject (assuming you're using 4.1 or newer).

So if your columns are already defaulting to utf8 then you're fine.

If you're using a different character set by default (not sure if Django even supports this) and only want some utf8 columns you could subclass `models.CharField` and override `db_type`. Here are the [Django docs for custom fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_type).